# Hacer un sistema de restauracion de una base de datos usando $_Files

Tags: php, html, mysql

Una duda independiente. Es posible hacer un sistema que restaure la base de datos de un sitio web usando $_FILES? La una forma que consegui hacerlo fue usando esta herramienta open source.

```
<?php 
   /**
* This file contains the Restore_Database class wich performs
* a partial or complete restoration of any given MySQL database
* @author Daniel López Azaña <daniloaz@gmail.com>
* @version 1.0
*/

/**
* Define database parameters here
*/

define("DB_USER", 'root');
define("DB_PASSWORD", '');
define("DB_NAME", 'prueba');
define("DB_HOST", 'localhost');
define("BACKUP_DIR", 'backups');
define("BACKUP_FILE", 'myphp-backup-prueba-20181106_133818.sql'); // Cambiale el nombre al sql mas nuevo
define("CHARSET", 'utf8');
define("DISABLE_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS", true); // Set to true if you are having foreign key constraint fails

/**
 * The Restore_Database class
 */
class Restore_Database {
/**
 * Host where the database is located
 */
var $host;

/**
 * Username used to connect to database
 */
var $username;

/**
 * Password used to connect to database
 */
var $passwd;

/**
 * Database to backup
 */
var $dbName;

/**
 * Database charset
 */
var $charset;

/**
 * Database connection
 */
var $conn;

/**
 * Disable foreign key checks
 */
var $disableForeignKeyChecks;

/**
 * Constructor initializes database
 */
function __construct($host, $username, $passwd, $dbName, $charset = 'utf8') {
    $this->host                    = $host;
    $this->username                = $username;
    $this->passwd                  = $passwd;
    $this->dbName                  = $dbName;
    $this->charset                 = $charset;
    $this->disableForeignKeyChecks = defined('DISABLE_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS') ? DISABLE_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS : true;
    $this->conn                    = $this->initializeDatabase();
    $this->backupDir               = defined('BACKUP_DIR') ? BACKUP_DIR : '.';
    $this->backupFile              = defined('BACKUP_FILE') ? BACKUP_FILE : null;
}

/**
 * Destructor re-enables foreign key checks
 */
function __destructor() {
    /**
     * Re-enable foreign key checks 
     */
    if ($this->disableForeignKeyChecks === true) {
        mysqli_query($this->conn, 'SET foreign_key_checks = 1');
    }
}

protected function initializeDatabase() {
    try {
        $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->passwd, $this->dbName);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            throw new Exception('ERROR connecting database: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
            die();
        }
        if (!mysqli_set_charset($conn, $this->charset)) {
            mysqli_query($conn, 'SET NAMES '.$this->charset);
        }

        /**
         * Disable foreign key checks 
         */
        if ($this->disableForeignKeyChecks === true) {
            mysqli_query($conn, 'SET foreign_key_checks = 0');
        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print_r($e->getMessage());
        die();
    }

    return $conn;
}

/**
 * Backup the whole database or just some tables
 * Use '*' for whole database or 'table1 table2 table3...'
 * @param string $tables
 */
public function restoreDb() {
    try {
        $sql = '';
        $multiLineComment = false;

        $backupDir = $this->backupDir;
        $backupFile = $this->backupFile;

        /**
         * Gunzip file if gzipped
         */
        $backupFileIsGzipped = substr($backupFile, -3, 3) == '.gz' ? true : false;
        if ($backupFileIsGzipped) {
            if (!$backupFile = $this->gunzipBackupFile()) {
                throw new Exception("ERROR: couldn't gunzip backup file " . $backupDir . '/' . $backupFile);
            }
        }

        /**
        * Read backup file line by line
        */
        $handle = fopen($backupDir . '/' . $backupFile, "r");
        if ($handle) {
            while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
                $line = ltrim(rtrim($line));
                if (strlen($line) > 1) { // avoid blank lines
                    $lineIsComment = false;
                    if (preg_match('/^\/\*/', $line)) {
                        $multiLineComment = true;
                        $lineIsComment = true;
                    }
                    if ($multiLineComment or preg_match('/^\/\//', $line)) {
                        $lineIsComment = true;
                    }
                    if (!$lineIsComment) {
                        $sql .= $line;
                        if (preg_match('/;$/', $line)) {
                            // execute query
                            if(mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql)) {
                                if (preg_match('/^CREATE TABLE `([^`]+)`/i', $sql, $tableName)) {
                                    $this->obfPrint("Se creo la tabla: `" . $tableName[1] . "`");
                                }
                                $sql = '';
                            } else {
                                throw new Exception("ERROR: SQL execution error: " . mysqli_error($this->conn));
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (preg_match('/\*\/$/', $line)) {
                        $multiLineComment = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            fclose($handle);
        } else {
            throw new Exception("ERROR: couldn't open backup file " . $backupDir . '/' . $backupFile);
        } 
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print_r($e->getMessage());
        return false;
    }

    if ($backupFileIsGzipped) {
        unlink($backupDir . '/' . $backupFile);
    }

    return true;
}

/*
 * Gunzip backup file
 *
 * @return string New filename (without .gz appended and without backup directory) if success, or false if operation fails
 */
protected function gunzipBackupFile() {
    // Raising this value may increase performance
    $bufferSize = 4096; // read 4kb at a time
    $error = false;

    $source = $this->backupDir . '/' . $this->backupFile;
    $dest = $this->backupDir . '/' . date("Ymd_His", time()) . '_' . substr($this->backupFile, 0, -3);

    $this->obfPrint('Gunzipping backup file ' . $source . '... ', 1, 1);

    // Remove $dest file if exists
    if (file_exists($dest)) {
        if (!unlink($dest)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Open gzipped and destination files in binary mode
    if (!$srcFile = gzopen($this->backupDir . '/' . $this->backupFile, 'rb')) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!$dstFile = fopen($dest, 'wb')) {
        return false;
    }

    while (!gzeof($srcFile)) {
        // Read buffer-size bytes
        // Both fwrite and gzread are binary-safe
        if(!fwrite($dstFile, gzread($srcFile, $bufferSize))) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    fclose($dstFile);
    gzclose($srcFile);

    // Return backup filename excluding backup directory
    return str_replace($this->backupDir . '/', '', $dest);
}

/**
 * Prints message forcing output buffer flush
 *
 */
public function obfPrint ($msg = '', $lineBreaksBefore = 0, $lineBreaksAfter = 1) {
    if (!$msg) {
        return false;
    }

    $msg = date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . ' - ' . $msg;
    $output = '';

    if (php_sapi_name() != "cli") {
        $lineBreak = "<br />";
    } else {
        $lineBreak = "\n";
    }

    if ($lineBreaksBefore > 0) {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $lineBreaksBefore; $i++) {
            $output .= $lineBreak;
        }                
    }

    $output .= $msg;

    if ($lineBreaksAfter > 0) {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $lineBreaksAfter; $i++) {
            $output .= $lineBreak;
        }                
    }

    if (php_sapi_name() == "cli") {
        $output .= "\n";
    }

    echo $output;

    if (php_sapi_name() != "cli") {
        ob_flush();
    }

    flush();
}
}

/**
* Instantiate Restore_Database and perform backup
*/
// Report all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// Set script max execution time
set_time_limit(900); // 15 minutes

if (php_sapi_name() != "cli") {
echo '<div style="font-family: monospace;">';
}

$restoreDatabase = new Restore_Database(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$result = $restoreDatabase->restoreDb(BACKUP_DIR, BACKUP_FILE) ? 'OK' : 'KO';
$restoreDatabase->obfPrint("Resultado: ".$result, 1);

if (php_sapi_name() != "cli") {
echo '</div>';
}
?>

</html>
```

Se puede modificar para usar $_Files?

Comment: ¿Tienes acceso directo a la base de datos? ¿En que formato tienes la copia de seguridad que quieres subir mediante `$_FILES`?

Comment: Si, ese es el usuario maestro. El formato es en .sql